# How to change height of UITableView cell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to show a comment on an app like in the following pictures. I'm using Xcode 9.4.1.

[image: app view]

I use the following code to hide the label:

```
if commentManager == nil {
    cell.managerReplyLabel.isHidden = true
    cell.ratingManagerLabel.isHidden = true
}
```

But it looks still like it has a space on it which I hidden two labels.

I try to use `cell.ratingManagerLabel.font.withSize(0)` or 
`cell.ratingManagerLabel.frame.size.height = 0` to change the label hight, but it doesn't work.

How to reduce the space?

*Update:*

I use storyboard to set the screen and auto-layout.

[image: autolayout]

```
import UIKit
import Cosmos

class RatingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingStar: CosmosView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingUserLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingManagerLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var managerReplyLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: Show tableViewCell code.

Comment: do you want to reduce the height of the cell ?

Comment: i use storyboard to set it, update it.

Comment: use self size tableview

Comment: Using `UIStackView` is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two easy solutions:

1. Set the text on both labels to `nil` (or `""`). Then the labels will have zero height.
2. Wrap the labels into a `UIStackView` with vertical layout direction. Then setting `.isHidden = true` will effectively remove the labels too.

Also note that you might need to call:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

to force the table to update height of its cells.

Comment: it works for number1, i'm sorry can you kindly provide a simple code about number2? thanks!!

Comment: @Peggy What's number 2?

Comment: how to use "Wrap the labels into a UIStackView with vertical layout direction. Then setting .isHidden = true will effectively remove the labels too."?

Comment: @Peggy Add `UIStackView` to your storyboard and put the labels inside. There is no code involved.

Comment: ohh! Sorry i didn’t realize it was a vertical stack view in storyboard. it looks good for this solution. thanks!!!

Answer (score 8):

Use the delegate method in your UITableView Class.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 200 //or whatever you need
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. this method will change all size for table view cell. but i only want to change height in some situation.

Comment: You need to use `switch` or `if ...else` statements to target the rows/cells you want to change the height for.

Answer (score 1):

use this tableview method for increasing and decreasing height of row

```
var selectedIndex = -1

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == selectedIndex {
            return 354
        }else {
            return 115
        }
    }
```